# Makefile variables: difference between "MY_FILE" and "obj-m"

Tags: c, makefile, linux-device-driver, gnu-make

I have two simple programs (application, driver) and a Makefile that dynamically compiles these applications. When I run "make test_prg", it compiles the application correctly. This doesn't, however, work for the driver "make test_drv".

~/test/test_prg/hello-world.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

~/test/test_drv/hello-world.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
int __init hello_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
void __exit hello_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Bye world\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

~/test/Makefile

```
MAKEFLAGS       := -B
DRV_PATH        := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PRG_PATH        := .

MY_PATH         := 
MY_TARGET       :=
MY_FILE         ?=

test_%: _setup_test_%
        make M=$(PWD) -C $(MY_PATH) MY_FILE=$@/$(MY_FILE) $(MY_TARGET)

build:
        gcc $(MY_FILE)

_setup_test_drv:
        $(eval MY_PATH=$(DRV_PATH))
        $(eval MY_TARGET=modules)
        $(eval obj-m=hello-world.o)
        echo $(obj-m) $(MY_PATH)

_setup_test_prg:
        $(eval MY_PATH=$(PRG_PATH))
        $(eval MY_TARGET=build)
        $(eval MY_FILE=hello-world.c)
```

The correct values are set, but it doesn't find the module to compile:

> ```
> echo hello-world.o /lib/modules/4.6.7-pd-4.6.y/build
> hello-world.o /lib/modules/4.6.7-pd-4.6.y/build
> make M=/home/timgru/test -C /lib/modules/4.6.7-pd-4.6.y/build MY_FILE=test_drv/ modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.7-pd-4.6.y'
>   Building modules, stage 2.
>   MODPOST 0 modules
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.7-pd-4.6.y'
> ```

Strangely, if I hard-code the "driver parameters", the driver's being compiled correctly:

~/test/test_drv/Makefile

```
obj-m:=hello-world.o
#hello-world-objs:=$(shell find . -name '*.c')

all:
    make -C/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

I'm trying to understand why the ~/test/Makefile solution for compiling the driver doesn't work. Furthermore, I would like to bypass this problem somehow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: *never* hard-code `make` in a makefile. Always use `$(MAKE)`.

Your makefile does not define `obj-m` when it is invoked with target `modules`. Correct would be

```make
obj-m :=
obj-m += hello-world.o

test_drv test_prg:
        $(MAKE) M=$(PWD) -C $(MY_PATH) $(MY_TARGET)

test_drv: MY_PATH   := $(DRV_PATH)
test_drv: MY_TARGET := modules
```

Here is the corrected version of your Makefile:

```perl
MAKEFLAGS := -B
DRV_PATH  := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PRG_PATH  := .

.PHONY: test_drv test_prg
test_drv test_prg:
    $(MAKE) M=$(PWD) -C $(MY_PATH) MY_FILE=$@/$(MY_FILE) $(MY_TARGET)

.PHONY: build
build:
    gcc $(MY_FILE)

test_drv: MY_PATH   := $(DRV_PATH)
test_drv: MY_TARGET := modules
# input values for "modules" & friends
obj-m               :=
obj-m               += hello-world.o

test_prg: MY_PATH   := $(PRG_PATH)
test_prg: MY_TARGET := build
test_prg: MY_FILE   := hello-world.c
```

Comment: Except I do define it. When you run `make test_drv` it calls the `test_%` target, which invokes `_setup_test_%`, in which obj-m is created. This method works for `make test_prg`. 

(Thanks for the tip).

Comment: But `make test_drv` calls `make modules` which processes the makefile again. Your makefile does not define `obj-m` when it is called with target `modules`.

Comment: `make test_prg` calls `make build` which only relies on `$(MY_FILE)`, which is defined directly on the `make` command line.

Comment: Calling `make` in a rule creates a new `make` instance. It **is not** a "function call" that gets executed in the same `make` instance.

Comment: Yes, I know calling `make` will instantiate another program which doesn't share the variables. If I would add a `modules` target to the makefile, it won't called because when I run `make test_drv`, `MY_PATH` will be set to `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`. (I've tested by adding `echo` to the `modules` target).

Comment: I think you do not understand how Linux kbuild system works. `M=` tells kbuild in which directory to find a file called  `Makefile` which gets *included* by kbuild and needs to define `obj-m`. If my suggested target-specific variable doesn't work, then this just means you can't make `obj-m` conditional at all.

Comment: Did a quick browse through kbuild. You can't define `obj-m` conditionially, i.e. the makefile must always define it. Updating my answer.

Comment: Not entirely, hence the question. The Makefile doesn't work and if you say it's included, it isn't executed thus this solution will not work (nor any other alike). I've made changes to mimic the Makefiles in the kernel by adding a `CONFIG_DRIVER=m`. Thank you :-)